# Jquery multiple actions with same key based on position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like users to scroll down a list with the arrow down key. This is implemented.

Users should be able to load the next list when they hit down on the last item. This is also implemented.

I don't want users to be able to hold the down key from the top of one list and never let go, loading more and more lists at the bottom.

Is there a way for me to "push" a keyup event to the client, saying that once they've reached the bottom of a list they must manually push the down arrow key again?

---

Edit: Adding some code, in case it helps.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 40:
      var lineID = Number($('.active').data('lineid'));
      if(lineID != Number($('body > span').last().data('lineid'))) {
        //update lineID to next number and activate next line
      }
      if(lineID == Number($('body > span').last().data('lineid'))) {
        //update location to next list article
      }
      break;
    default: return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

What I need to do now, is somehow prevent a user from holding the down key and loading all lists after reaching the bottom. I would ideally think that "pushing" a key up event somehow would be satisfactory. As that would allow the user to scroll quickly to the bottom but then have to hit "down" again to load the next list, thereby making it easy to reach the bottom and prevent loading the next list by accident.

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @SandeepNayak sadly not here, but somewhere I assume.

Comment: @victoroux did you tried my code ?

Comment: @SandeepNayak I've updated the question with some code

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for that

```
// A variable to check when user is at the end of page
var endOfPage = false;

// keydown handler
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if(endOfPage==false){
     // Do our thing
  switch(e.keyCode){
    case 40: // down

      console.log('down');
      break;

    case 38: // up

      console.log('up');
      break;

  }
}
});
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       //user is at the bottom of page
       endOfPage = true;
   }
});

// keyup handler
$(document).keyup(function(e){
   endOfPage = false;
});
```

Comment: What happens when the user never lifts the down key? If they keep it pressed the whole time then there is no key up event and therefore no way to stop the user from sending a down key at the bottom of the page. Or am I mis-reading?

Comment: Yes but you are forgetting that i have made another control so when he goes at the end of the page the variable would change to true and when you make the control if the variable is false you will let him scroll. Read the coments in my code

Comment: You should place your code where i have make a console.log('down');

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. I will try to implement this method. And get back to you.

Comment: You had the function to get when the user is at the end of the page if my function doesn't work then just replace with yours :)